# What happens to wait() if multiple child process terminate simultaneously?

Tags: linux, process, wait

Say I create a process with multiple child process and I call `wait()` in the main process. If one child terminates, its `pid` is returned. But what happens if a couple of child process terminate simultaneously? The call should return with one of them, and a second call should return with the other, right? Is there a particular order in which they will return (maybe there is a precedence to the child with lower pid)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.**

SUSv4 leaves explicitly unspecified in which order (if any) child processes are reaped by one or several `wait` calls. There is also no "accidential" order that you could rely on, since different Linux kernel versions perform differently. (Source: M. Kerrisk, TLPI, 26.1.1, page 542).

---

**Somewhat related trivia:**
You might wonder why you can reliably wait on several child processes that terminate concurrently *at all*. If you think about how signals work, you might be inclined to believe that it is perfectly possible to lose child termination signals. Signals, a well-known fact, *are not queued* (except for realtime signals, but `SIGCHLD` isn't one!). Which means that if you go strictly by the letter of the book, then clearly several children terminating could cause some child termination signals becoming lost!
You can only call `wait` once at the same time, so you can at most consume one signal synchronously as it is generated, and have a second one made pending before your next call to `wait`. It appears that there is no way to account for any other signals that are generated in the mean time.

Luckily, that isn't the case. Waiting on child processes demonstrably works fine. Always, 100%. But why?

The reason is simple, the kernel is "cheating". If a child process exits while you are blocked in `wait`, there is no question as to what's happening. The signal is immediately delivered, the status information is being filled in, the parent unblocks, and the child process goes * poof *.
On the other hand, if a child is exiting and the parent isn't in a `wait` call (or if the parent *is* in a `wait` call reaping another child), the system converts the exiting process to a "zombie".
Now, when the parent process performs a `wait`, and there are any zombie processes, it won't block waiting for a signal to be generated (which may never happen if all the children have already exited!). Instead, it will just reap one of the zombies, pretending the signal was delivered just now.

Comment: But what happens if I'm calling `wait` from a signal handler for `SIGCHLD`? If the second child terminates while I'm still handling the signal, the `SIGCHLD` is blocked I won't get another `SIGCHLD` signal for the second child, have I understood you correctly?

Comment: Interesting question, although you would normally never want to do any such thing. It is of course strictly legal to call `wait` from a handler, but it can block indefinitely whereas handlers should normally return "soon". But of course, _you're allowed_ to do that, and the expectation is that it works somehow. I can't tell you what happens in this case, sorry. My guess would be that the OS will "cheat" again and simply have `wait` reap the terminating process whether the actual signal is blocked or not. Otherwise `wait` could never possibly return, which would be a deadlock by design.